# Android Intent service with a blocking read (inputStream.read() ) does't recieve data or gets destroyed after a while

Tags: android, service, real-time, intentservice, android-intentservice

Reading a stream of events works fine for sometime ( even in background , foreground ) , after a while in background, it doesn't read any events , neither the service is destroyed.

Need it to read events in background. I want to resume reading events when the activity is resumed by checking if it not actively reading events. currently i am checking if the service is running from getSystemService list. Basically i just a single event stream reader and not spawning multiple stream readers. (I know it's a bad design , but right now thats not the problem).

```
private boolean isEventsServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.xxxxx.EventsListenerService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


private void startReadingEvents() {//gets called from onHandleIntent
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(ServerCalls.SERVER_ADDR + "/stream/" + ServerCalls.streamId + eventsRenewPath);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            inpStream = con.getInputStream();
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader((inpStream)));
            inputStream.useDelimiter("\r\n");
            boolean keepReading = true;
            while(keepReading){
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String bytes;
                while(inputStream.hasNext()){
                    bytes = inputStream.next();
                    if(bytes==null) return; //reinitialize
                    if(bytes.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        break; // stop word reached
                    }
                    str.append(bytes);
                    str.append("\n");
                }
                if(str.length()>0) {
                    Log.e(Config.ERR_LOG_TAG, "event found andbroadcasting...");
                    publishEvent(str.toString());
                }
                else{
                    keepReading = false;
                    Log.e(Config.ERR_LOG_TAG, "Empty event found ");

                    publishEvent(null);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(Config.ERR_LOG_TAG, "Scanner is closed , restarting : "+(3-count));
            if(count-->0){ //retry count times.
            startReadingEvents();
            return;
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check your internet connection" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    Log.e(Config.ERR_LOG_TAG, "Events listener is stopped ");
    return;
}
```

Comment: define `after a while`

Comment: I am not sure of exact time, it is ~10-15 minutes. The events happen approximately every 5 minutes.  Its not problem with the scanner, It's with underlying inputstream.read() , the socket doesn't receive data in background , even though data is sent from server, it just blocks without exiting the intentservice. I am out of ideas. any debugging procedure is much appreciated.

Comment: the system will eventually stop your service. you need a foreground service for really long existence.

Comment: Yeah , but its not being stopped/killed. i suspect its a hardware based bug as also mentioned in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655624/bluetooth-inputstream-read-doesnt-return-data-and-blocks-forever#comment54571169_26655624] ,I have made use of  Android Service(Speifically overriden the onStartCommand of intentService) now and a kill off old connection if more than 10 minutes have elapsed.  Seems to do the job for me.